# awk script to remove ASCII from file type

Tags: regex, scripting, sed, awk

Here is a simple command

```
file * | awk '/ASCII text/ {gsub(/:/,"",$1); print $1}' | xargs chmod -x
```

I am not able to understand the use of awk in the above as showed.
How is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a deleted answer which came pretty close to avoiding the problems with whitespace or colons in filenames and the output of `file`. I've voted to undelete the answer, but I'm going to go ahead and post some improvements to it and add some explanation.

```
file -0 * | awk -F '\0' '$2 ~ /ASCII text/ {print $1 "\0"}' | xargs -0 chmod -x
```

Since nulls aren't allowed in filenames, it's safe to use them as delimiters. Each step in this pipeline uses nulls. `file` outputs them, `awk` accepts them in input and outputs them and xargs accepts them in input. I've also made the match specific to the description field so it won't trigger a false positive in the perhaps unusual case of a file which is named something like "ASCII text" but in fact its contents are not.

As others have said, the AWK command you posted matches lines of output from the `file` command that include "ASCII text" somewhere in the line. Then *every* colon is deleted (since `gsub()` is a global substitution) from field one which is the colon-space-delimited filename. A potential problem occurs if the filename contains either a colon or a space (or both or multiples). The filename will get truncated and the `chmod` will fail or might even be falsely triggered on a file with a similar name (e.g. "foo bar" and "foo" both exist, "foo" is not an ASCII text file so you don't want it to be touched, but "foo bar" gets truncated to "foo" and oops!). The reason spaces are potential problems is that AWK, by default, does field splitting on spaces and tabs.

Breakdown of the AWK portion of the pipeline you posted:

- `/ASCII text/ {` - for each line that matches the regular expression
- `gsub(/:/,"",$1);` - for each colon (as a regular expression) in the first field, substitute an empty string
- `print $1}` - print the thus modified first field

Comment: I was trying to understand the answer you gave.Now I understand.Just one doubt remains why did you used $2 in your answer above?What does it represents?Also you have used -0 every where is it the null character you are saying?

Comment: @RegisteredUser: `$2` is the way AWK refers to the second field in the input (`$1` is the first, `$3`, etc, and `$NF` is the last). Yes, `-0` is an option switch for the `file` utility that causes it to use ASCII nulls for delimiters instead of whitespace. The same option causes `xargs` to use nulls for input delimiters. The `\0` is an octal escape that represents ASCII null and I've used it twice in the AWK command. Once with the `-F` option for the input field delimiter and once concatenated with the output of the `print` command. This way each element of the pipeline use null delimiters.

Comment: ok thanks for the message if you can give me some link I want to read more about -0 thing.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: [`man file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) and [`man xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs), also [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) (`-print0`) and [`man grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (`-z` and `-Z`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing but it looks like it's extracting the part before the `:` in the output of the file command (i.e. the filename). The gsub part will remove the `:` in the filename and so something like `foo.txt: ASCII text` will become `foo.txt ASCII text`. Then, the print will print the first item in the space separated list (in this case, the filename `foo.txt`). All these files will be made unexecutable by the chmod.

This looks quite tedious. It's probably easier to just say `awk -F: '{print $1}'` after grepping instead of the whole substitution trick. Also, this will break if the filename has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

It's using `file` to determine the type (contents) of each file, then selecting the ones that are ASCII text and removing everything from the first colon (which is assumed to be the separator between the filename and file type; this is fragile when file names have colons in them; as Noufel noted, it's also doing it the hard way), then using `xargs` to batch then up and clear the execute bits.  (The usual reason for doing this is files transferred from Windows, which doesn't have execute bits so often all files end up with execute bits set as seen by Unixes.)

The breakage on spaces is fixable; `xargs` understands quoting.  I would break on the *last* colon instead of the first, though, since `file` doesn't usually include colons in its ASCII text type strings.